# What does "Range" Mean in Electrical Circuits?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, electrical-panel

The switching have been tripping a lot at my apartment, sometimes an entire wall is completely powerless, but the rest of the rooms are just fine.

Usually, I just need to turn the switch off and on to regain electricity in that area of the house.

There are a few things, though, that I don't understand about the circuit shown below:

[image]

For example, I don't know what "Range" means, I know that "GFI" means Ground Fault Interrupter, but I don't know if it helps at all to turn the switch on/off

Any clarification will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like you have a failing breaker or some sort of wiring fault in that wall; or have overloaded that circuit.

Comment: Might want to keep track of which one in particular keeps tripping, and then check what sort of devices you have on those - i.e. fridge, vacuum, blender, microwave, etc.

Comment: The tripping is all over the house. Sometimes it's the kitchen; some other times it's the bedroom; sometimes is the living room. It all started because I plugged in an iron that caused the entire house's lights the flicker, and ever since then the tripping seems to be random.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A "*Range*" is a freestanding combination oven/cooktop device.

[image: Range]

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, a range is another name for a freestanding electric oven/cooktop combination.  As to your tripping problem -- random trips on different circuits with no sign of an overload is a sign that the breaker panel busbars are on their way out, and trying to burn your house down in the process.  Get a good electrician (or three) in there to get the panel replaced!

Comment: I just hope the "burn your house down" wasn't literal :)

Comment: @AlanChavez -- sadly, it can be in some cases -- I'd get an electrician out there to look at the panel as soon as feasible.

Comment: In this context, it is indeed electric (of course), but a "range", in general, could also be wood-, oil-, or gas-burning — e.g. http://www.waterfordstanley.com/news-media/stanley-image-gallery/stanley-range-cookers

Answer (score 0):

"Range" has been answered. "GFI" as you surmise, is ground fault interrupt.  Those circuits are labeled thusly because the kitchen counter and bathroom circuits are required to have GFI protection.  No pic of actual breakers in your post, but if they aren't GFCI breakers, the label is telling you that at least the first outlet (or dead front switch) downstream from the breaker is a GFCI outlet.

Answer (score -1):

The range is the oven, more or less the same thing.

Comment: This answer needs fleshing out...

Comment: A range is not an oven, a range is an oven + cooktop as a single unit.